# How to alias an object method?

Tags: c++, alias, typedef

I have a complicated class I'm wrapping (meaning I'm creating a small object that only exposes the stuff my users need out of the complicated class):

```
class Complicated{
  public:
    void long_name();
}

typedef Complicated Simple;
```

I'm able to call `Simple().long_name()` but what I really want is to rename it to `Simple.short_name()`...

The reason I don't use the actual `Complicated` class is that it is:

1. Very long
2. Very complex
3. I only need to expose to my users 4 methods out of ~50

At first I tried to contain `Complicated` inside a `SimpleWrapper`:

```
class SimpleWrapper{
  private:
    Complicated m_complicated;
};
```

but this is impossible (at least I'm unable to use it) because the way to create `Complicated` is a static function that returns `unique_ptr<Complicated>` - meaning that if I initialize my `m_complicated` with that, I can't pass my object to others

---

[MRP](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```
#include <memory>

class Complicated {
 public:
  void do_stuff() {}  // do the actual stuff
};

std::unique_ptr<Complicated> get_complicated() {
  return std::make_unique<Complicated>();
}

class Wrapper {
 public:
  Wrapper() = default;
  void do_stuff() {}  // calls the m_complicated->do_stuff()
  //void do_stuff() { m_complicated->do_stuff(); }

 private:
  // TODO: Uncomment the line below to expose the bug. Also replace the comments
  // on the do_stuff function
  // std::unique_ptr<Complicated> m_complicated;
};

Wrapper get_wrapper() { return Wrapper(); }

void user_function_that_wants_to_do_stuff(Wrapper w){};
// I can also use this function instead - it would involve a more complicated
// code so I want to use the function above - and call from Wrapper to
// Complicated's functions
void user_function_that_wants_to_do_stuff(std::unique_ptr<Complicated> c) {
  c->do_stuff();
};

int main() {
  auto w = get_wrapper();
  user_function_that_wants_to_do_stuff(w);

  auto c = get_complicated();
  user_function_that_wants_to_do_stuff(std::move(c));
  return 0;
}
```

Just compiled and ran with `clang++ <file_name> && ./a.out`

```
$ clang++ --version

Ubuntu clang version 15.0.0-++20220718052906+477c2c6f4a5a-1~exp1~20220718173011.318
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
```

Comment: If you don't want a wrapper class, you'll need a free function that calls the member function you want. But a wrapper class should be viable too; yes, a `unique_ptr` member would make it move-only, but that's not that big of a limitation. The users of the unwrapped class already have to deal with a non-copyable `unique_ptr`.

Comment: `#define long_name short_name`, but this will get you into trouble. Other alternatives may involve combining free functions with member function pointers. Not sure what you mean by "I can't pass my object to other" btw. You can create a `std::shared_ptr` from a `std::unique_ptr` when in doubt `std::unique_ptr`s can be moved...

Comment: Not sure I understand you - Is it possible to have an object, holding a unique_ptr member - and then pass that object around (by value, by reference, by copy/move Ctor)? I wasn't able to make that happen

Comment: Pass it by reference (or `const` reference, if you only want to read from it).

Comment: @PaulSanders not sure how - I have a function that creates the `Wrapper` object, and that breaks everything I try to do... Once I remove the `unique_ptr` from the `Wrapper` definition, everything is OK. Once it's back - I get a lot of errors :(

Comment: By value - yes, it can be moved (either with `std::move` or just because it's an rvalue), but not copied. By reference - yes, always. The rules are exactly the same as if you were passing `unique_ptr` directly, assuming you didn't break the wrapper in some way.

Comment: *"get a lot of errors"* Having 10k rep, I'd expect you to know that we need a [mcve] for those. :P

Comment: Yep - @HolyBlackCat - but it's 1:30 AM, and I need to create an MRP that doesn't expose anything - I'll upload it tomorrow...

Comment: Perhaps have Simple privately-inherit from Complicated, and add the four methods to Simple that call the appropriate methods on Complicated.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner sounds good, but I feel it breaks my design, as I won't have a wrapper, I'll have a derived class with even more logic. Its kinda nitpicking I guess, but it feels like maybe a bad way to solve this - like my design should have been better somehow

Comment: @CIsForCookies I also like a good PIMPL idiom... can you make a new static function that returns a `std::unique_ptr<Simple>` and have your clients call that instead of the Complicated-static-function ?  Then the four `Simple` methods can simply call through to the corresponding methods in the private `Simple::std_unique_ptr<Complicated>` object.

Comment: I think you could simply write `void user_function_that_wants_to_do_stuff(Wrapper &w){};`. unless you really want to move.... In any case, it would be the as when you use `unique_ptr` directly.

Comment: Either `user_function_that_wants_to_do_stuff(std::move(w));` or make the function take the parameter by reference. Or `user_function_that_wants_to_do_stuff(get_wrapper())`, then the move happens implicitly.

Comment: OK - things look good in the example I gave, but not in my real code. I'm still trying to figure out the differences. One thing that blocks the private inheritance option is that `Complicated` is pure abstract (the way to get an instance is via `static::create` method)... I think the main issue I have is trying to `vector.push_back(Wrapper)` which invokes `Wrapper` CCtor, which is deleted because `Wrapper` holds a `unique_ptr` that deletes its CCtor - makes sense? - if so, what can I do?